# How to make element scrollable if it's height is dynamic (dependent on parent)?

Tags: html, css

I want to make element scrollable if it's content is becoming too large to fit in parent's `max-height`. The problem is that it overflows parent instead of adding scrollbar.

I know that providing `height` or `max-height` in pixels to element would fix the issue but I cannot do that because the height of the element is not known.
Link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollable-height-ewfbmo?file=/src/App.js
(I want purple section to be scrollable)

Comment: Which part do you wish to make scrollable? The purple section or the whole section?

Comment: @Harrison Purple section only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to scroll the purple region:

Just add `overflow: auto` to the .body class (the parent of the purple region)

I forked your code-sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollable-height-forked-9hvrpy?file=/src/styles.css